# How do I upload a file to a datastore using vmware workstation?

Tags: virtualization, vmware, vmware-workstation, esxi

I have setup ESXi 6.5 and created my first VM. In workstation 15, I can't find my way to upload the ISO file needed to install the OS to the datastore. Any Tips ?

Answer (score 2):

open ssh service and use winscp to connect to your esxi
and here is a full tutorial how to do it

https://graspingtech.com/transfer-files-vmware-esxi-6-5-host/

and don't. forget that on ur esxi data store path is
/vmfs/volumes/data_store_name

Comment: Welcome on the SU! Please give more detailed answers.

Comment: sorry for the short reply, I edited the answer, and added a link to tutorial how to do it in details